# Class diagram for variable member with the type of `std::vector<T>`

Tags: c++, templates, uml, stdvector, class-diagram

```
class Foo{};

class Demo
{
public:
    std::vector<Foo> foo_vec;
};
```

How to draw the relationship between them?

How to tell the others that the `foo_vec` is `vector` in the class diagram(I found [this](https://forums.visual-paradigm.com/t/using-stl-containers-like-std-vector-myclass-in-class-diagram-and-to-generate-c-code/16320))? And some posts tell me to add notation `<:vector>` on the line that represent composition.

Comment: *foo_vec is vector* is not what class diagram cares, ofcourse there is nothing prevent you adding a remark.

Comment: In UML style diagrams there is a relation of containment, and it can be either `1 to 1`, or `1 to many`. In your case it's `1 to many` containment.

Comment: Demo is composed of 0..* Foos , vector is irrelevant in UML

Comment: Would this question cover your problem as well? https://stackoverflow.com/q/71352348/3723423

Comment: @Christophe Aren't those diagrams for templates, unrelated to this question?

Comment: @KansaiRobot Thanks for the opportunity to clarify. `std::vector<T>` is a template (in case of doubt, you may cross-check the vector header of your favorite implementation) so it is fully related to the question. At the same time, the question is how much you would like to leak implementation details in the diagram.  In my answer below, you may find different notations that can be used, between full focus on template nature of the vector, and hidden implementation details.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disclose the details of the implementation, you could go for something as developed as:

[image]

The key of this design is to disclose that vector is a templated class, and that it is instantiated by **binding** the template parameter `T` to the class `Foo`. To put `Foo` in the picture,  you could either just show it at the instantiation level, but I preferred to show some kind of relation with `T`.  I used here a realization,  since `T` implicitly defines in the C++ semantic an interface for the template parameter, and `Foo` is expected to implement this (implicit) interface.  I also used composition, since C++ vectors are by value, and the vector owns the lifecycle of its elements.

Unfortunately, this makes the design look more complex than it is in reality.  Moreover it doesn't show the full reality of a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) that has a second template parameter `Allocator`. Last but not least, to be fully transparent, you should use a qualified composition, with a `std::vector::size_type` qualifier (to document that there is an indexed access possible).  You'd end-up with a very complex diagram.

I therefore recommend to consider a simplified approach.  Since everybody knows what a `std::vector` is,  you may use the more compact (and still legit) form of a direct binding,  assuming that the template details are defined elsewhere:

[image]

This is very close to your implementation and stays very readable.  However,  you could simplify one step further:  is `vector`  a fundamental design choice?  Or is it just one practical way to implement a one-to-many composition?  If the real intent is just that `Demo` may be composed of several `Foo` you could be as simple as:

[image]

Here you would let to the implementer to chose the best way to implement the composition instead of graving the implementation choice in the marble of your model.

Comment: Should I add the multiply(i.e.: `0...*`) in the last diagram. If I add the said multiply, it's misleading that somebody may think there are many `vector<foo>`(i.e.: `vector<vector<foo>>`)..

Comment: For the first diagram, why you say `T` is a composition  of  `vector`?

Comment: @John yes 0..* would be better. The ambiguity is due to the naming of the property, which bears its type. This is no longer seen as a good practice by the way. Call it foo of foos (there are some debate about that) or something that says something about which foos it is. The vector is only the mean to the end. If you think it’s important to keep the vector as something to be modelled, then consider the second diagram which makes a distinction between the container and its eleements. you’d have multiplicity  1 then  0..* . Dot notation could be used on the vector end of left association

Comment: @John aggregation, shared (white diamond) and composite (black diamond) are placed on the side of the whole and not the side of the part. Do the first diagram says that vector is the composite whole made of plenty of T componenents/parts ;-)